# How to prevent Checkboxes to call onChange too soon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, checkbox

Here's the code:

```
 Checkbox(
   value: value,
   onChanged: (newValue) {
         setState(() => value = newValue);
         
         // Restructure data based on new value
         _restructureData(newValue);
      }
   activeColor: Colors.orange,
   materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
   tristate: true,
 );
```

However, since `tristate = true`, so if you are in `null` position going to `true` you need to press twice (`null` => `false` => `true`). But this also means that `_restructureData(newValue)` is called twice.

So how do I call `_restructureData(newValue)` only once the user finish tapping the check box whether it is once, twice or how many times he/she wants to press it before he stops?

Answer (score 0):

Store whether the checkbox has already been tapped with a boolean in the `State` of the surrounding widget. If the surrounding widget is not already stateful, it's necessary to make it stateful.

Example:

```
// Part of parent widget's state
bool isFirstTap = true;


// Somewhere in build
Checkbox(
  value: value,
  onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() => value = newValue);
        
        if(isFirstTap) {
          // Restructure data based on new value
          _restructureData(newValue);
          isFirstTap = false;
        }
     }
  activeColor: Colors.orange,
  materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
  tristate: true,
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could delay the execution of `_restructureData` using a timer, if the user press the checkbox again before the timer expired, you cancel it so it doesn't run. The key is to find the correct duration for the timer.

```
Checkbox(
    value: value,
    onChanged: (newValue) {
        setState(() => value = newValue);

        // cancel the timer if not null and running
        _t?.cancel();

        // delay the execution of _restructureData
        _t = Timer(Duration(seconds: DURATION_OF_YOUR_CHOICE), () {
            // Restructure data based on new value
            _restructureData(newValue);
        });
    }
    activeColor: Colors.orange,
    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
    tristate: true,
);
```